# the java send entity to redis stream convert to base64

Tags: java, redis, redis-streams

When I tried to send object data to redis stream(`Redis Version: 7.0.8`) using java(java 11) like this:

```
package com.dolphin.soa.post.common.mq;

import com.dolphin.soa.post.model.custom.NicknameEdit;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.ObjectRecord;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.RecordId;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.stream.StreamRecords;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StreamMessageProducer {

    private final RedisTemplate<String, NicknameEdit> redisTemplate;

    public void sendRecord(String streamKey, String nickname) {
        NicknameEdit nicknameEdit = new NicknameEdit();
        nicknameEdit.setNickname(nickname);
        ObjectRecord<String, NicknameEdit> record = StreamRecords.newRecord()
                .in(streamKey)
                .ofObject(nicknameEdit)
                .withId(RecordId.autoGenerate());
        RecordId recordId = redisTemplate.opsForStream()
                .add(record);
    }
}
```

the data in redis shows like this:

```
{
    "\"X2NsYXNz\"": "\"Y29tLmRvbHBoaW4uc29hLnBvc3QubW9kZWwuY3VzdG9tLlN5c0V2ZW50\"",
    "\"ZGF0YS5fY2xhc3M=\"": "\"Y29tLmRvbHBoaW4uc29hLnBvc3QubW9kZWwuY3VzdG9tLk5pY2tuYW1lRWRpdA==\"",
}
```

it looks like the send process automatically convert the object fields to base64. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the `NicknameEdit` define:

```
package com.dolphin.soa.post.model.custom;

import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
public class NicknameEdit implements Serializable {
    /**
     * admin_users.id
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    private Long userId;

    /**
     * admin_users.nickname
     *
     * @mbggenerated
     */
    private String nickname;
}
```

Is it possible to close the base64 encoding and just send the plain text json string?

Comment: "*what should I do to fixed this issue?*" - What is here to fix? Why not keep the base64 encoded value? What do you want instead?

Comment: I want the json with plain text without any extra encoding. because the send process using java, the consumer process using rust. if enoded, it is a bit complex to parse in rust client.

Comment: Have you verified that the data is correct? I have converted the fileds, and they convert to `{"_class": "com.dolphin.soa.post.model.custom.SysEvent", "data._class": "com.dolphin.soa.post.model.custom.NicknameEdit"}`.

Comment: I tried to send the plain text without object entiry, and the message is plain text now. it look like this `{
    "payload": "{\"data\":{\"nickname\":\"jxq\",\"userId\":103},\"id\":706376887005974528,\"msgType\":\"NICKNAME_UPDATE\"}"
}`